# How to select item and put into a seperate box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created tables of items and need them to be moved to a separate floating box (follows website users scroll when clicking an 'add' button).

At the moment I have created tables of items and managed to create the floating box:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  function getScrollTop() {
    if (typeof window.pageYOffset !== 'undefined') {
      return window.pageYOffset;
    }

    var d = document.documentElement;
    if (d.clientHeight) {
      return d.scrollTop;
    }
    return document.body.scrollTop;
  }

  window.onscroll = function() {
    var box = document.getElementById('box'),
      scroll = getScrollTop();

    if (scroll <= 28) {
      box.style.top = "50px";
    } else {
      box.style.top = (scroll + 2) + "px";
    }
  };

};
```

```css
 #box {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   background-color: #dad9c7;
   margin-left: 200px;
   left: 70%;
   width: 200px;
   height: 50px;
   border: 5px solid #393c3d;
   text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <u><h2>Batteries</h2></u> 
  <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter border">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Battery</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Capacity</th>
        <th>discharge</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>List</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Turnigy nano-tech 1000mAh</td>
        <td>99g</td>
        <td>1000mAh</td>
        <td>25~50C</td>
        <td>$10.15</td>
        <td>Add</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div id='box'><u>Parts List</u>
</div>
```

Help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Where is your click event for the Add "button"?

Comment: <button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>  myFunction moveTo() {
    box.moveTo(150, 150);
    box.focus();
}